# Collaborating on a repository with mercurial

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I own a repository but I have someone else making changes or adding new files sometimes. We are using mercurial and bitbucket right now. We us Pycharm as our IDE which handles most of the VCS features.

Is this the correct process that he would follow to add a new file/changes?

```
hg branch <branch>
hg add
hg commit -m "message"
hg push -b <branch> --new-branch
```

Then, on my end, I would merge this branch with the default branch and approve it.

Am I missing something? Would there be a separate branch for each file (or group of files) he created/modified? Should we use a fork instead?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct process that he would follow to add a new file/changes?

No

> Am I missing something?

Yes. In short - "...miss all...". You have to re-read [Mercurial ABC](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/) or [Mercurial Kick Start](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/basic/#working-with-others) and choose usable for your workflow (without a heap of useless named branches at least)